# How many different ways is it possible to carry this ladder?

Tags: combinatorics

In a certain game, to climb a 5-step ladder you are allowed to jump once as many steps as you want, stop to collect a toast and go back up as many steps as you like. In addition, you can go down once to one of the previous steps (as long as you have not reached the top), collect a toast and go back up. How many different ways can you climb this ladder?
What i thought: First, note that you cannot go down using just 2 degrees or 3 degrees.

You can go down the ladder using 1 step at a time: 1 - 1 - 1 - 1 - 1.

Using 1 step and 2 steps, we have the following possibilities:

2 - 2 - 1

2 - 1 - 2

1 - 2 - 2

2 - 1 - 1 - 1

1 - 2 - 1 - 1

1 - 1 - 2 - 1

1 - 1 - 1 - 2

Comment: I thought you could only skip a step once.  How is $2-2-1$ possible?

Comment: @saulspatz I thought I had a ladder with N steps. And you could choose to go down 1, 2, or 3 steps at a time with each move.

Comment: That doesn't seem to be at all what your question says, though.  I have great difficulty understanding what you wrote.  Nowhere does is say you have a choice of $1,2$ or $3$ steps for example.  Please try to clarify your question.

Comment: @saulspatz Forgive my friend! Can you understand the statement now?

Comment: Are you carrying the ladder or climbing it?  As many steps should include 1,2,3,4, and 5.  If no negative values allowed

Answer (score 1):

If you can take any number of steps, using the binary scheme it's easy to show that there are 16 ways.

```
00000 5
00001 4,1
00010 3,1,1
00011 3,2
00100 2,1,2
00101 2,1,1,1
00110 2,2,1
00111 2,3
01000 1,1,3
01001 1,1,2,1
01010 1,1,1,1,1
01011 1,1,1,2
01100 1,2,2
01101 1,2,1,1
01110 1,3,1
01111 1,4
```

Comment: I would like an elementary solution

Comment: I can't think of any other solution being simpler.  Please post if you find one. You just count the groups of digits. The count is just $2^{(n-1)}$, but this gives the construction of the solutions easily...